# Restore an Android Backup to an Android Emulator

Tags: backup, android-emulator

Is it possible to backup my phone, and restore it to my computer to run under and android emulator? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Do you want to backup only the apps, app data, settings, etc. or complete phone backup (encompassing partitions)?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, it should be possible. In order to do it, you need a custom recovery in your phone to perform the backup and a custom recovery, too, to perform the replacement in the emulator.

[TWRP has a custom recovery for the Android emulator](http://twrp.me/devices/androidemulator.html) and it's currently under TWRP's support. If you have the same recovery in your phone, it could be an option to perform the backup (make sure you're backing up only the data and not everything else, system images between your device and the emulator are probably different).

Although seems like an impossible task, by playing with the TWRP settings you could get your phone's backup to work on your emulator. You just need to handle the inconsistencies between the two of them.

Comment: My point is OP didn't really make it clear whether requires only Apps+Data backup or full system backup. If we consider only Apps+Data as you did so, why not use [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=en) or any other apps data backup app? Not that I deny your answer, but if the goal is only to backup Apps+Data, then why take the hard route when easy is at next door.